# Unable to use multiple ORDER BY in php using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Am trying to use `order by` date and price low to high in this statement

```
SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle' ORDER BY pdt DESC, prs ASC
```

i used `echo $query;` to get the query and here is how i did,

*looking for* ORDER BY pdt DESC, is default query i want `prs` to be user option .

when i select order by `low to high` or `high to low` the statement changes but query does nothing, **its not sorting by price**

How do i sort by `prs` any solution?

`pdt` means `Date` and `prs` means `Price`

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="sortby">
     <li class="dropdown-item">
         <div class="md-radio my-1">
              <input type="radio" class="filter_all sort" name="sort" id="asc" value="ASC">
              <label for="asc">Price : Low to High</label>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
           <div class="md-radio my-1">
                <input type="radio" class="filter_all sort" name="sort" id="desc" value="DESC">
                <label for="desc">Price : High to Low</label>
           </div>
       </li>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            filter_data();
            function filter_data() {
                $.post(
                        "fetch.php",
                        {
                            action: 'fetch_data',
                            cate: get_filter('cate'),
                            brand: get_filter('brand'),
                            model: get_filter('model'),
                            sort: get_filter('sort'),
                            date: get_filter('date')
                        }
                )
                        .done(function (data) {
                            $('.filter_data').html(data);
                        });
            }
            function get_filter(class_name) {
                var filter = [];
                $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function () {
                    filter.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filter;
            }
            $('.filter_all').click(function () {
                filter_data();
            });
        });
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' AND mca='Vehicle'";

if (!empty($_POST['cate'])) {
    $query .= " AND sca IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['cate']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['cate'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['brand'])) {
    $query .= " AND product_brand IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['brand']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['brand'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}

if (!empty($_POST['model'])) {
    $query .= " AND mdl IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['model']) - 1) . "?)";
} else {
    $_POST['model'] = []; // in case it is not set 
}
$query .= " ORDER BY pdt DESC";
if (!empty($_POST['sort'])) {
    if ($_POST["sort"][0] == "ASC" || $_POST["sort"][0] == "DESC") { //simplistic whitelist
        $query .= ", prs " . $_POST['sort'][0];
    }
}
echo $query;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$params = array_merge($_POST['cate'], $_POST['brand'], $_POST['model']);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_row = $stmt->rowCount();
$output = '';
```

Comment: What is `pdt`? You realize that the query as you have it will sort on that field first, and `prs` will only be a tie-breaker between records where `pdt` is the same?

Comment: @GregSchmidt `pdt` is `product date` and `prs` is `price`

Comment: So, what I expect should be happening here is that you'll have things sorted by date, and things with the same date are then sorted by price. Does that match what you're seeing?

Comment: This isn't related to PHP. It is just the language you are using to execute the query. Nor is it related to AJAX.

Comment: @GregSchmidt **NO** By default it should load by `date` when `price` is triggered and the query should go by `order by price` only.

Comment: Well then, you should not be including the "pdt DESC" in every single query you do, only when the price sort isn't requested.

Comment: Then you need to skip adding `ORDER BY pdt DESC` when `price` is triggered.

Comment: Yes, When price is triggered it should skip adding `ORDER BY pdt DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a third button for "Sort by date".

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="sortby">
  <li class="dropdown-item">
    <div class="md-radio my-1">
      <input type="radio" class="filter_all sort" name="sort" id="asc" value="ASC">
      <label for="asc">Price : Low to High</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-item">
    <div class="md-radio my-1">
      <input type="radio" class="filter_all sort" name="sort" id="desc" value="DESC">
      <label for="desc">Price : High to Low</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-item">
    <div class="md-radio my-1">
      <input type="radio" class="filter_all sort" name="sort" id="date" value="date">
      <label for="date">Date : High to Low</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

```
if (empty($_POST['sort']) || $_POST['sort'][0] == "date") {
    $query .= " ORDER BY pdt DESC";
} elseif ($_POST["sort"][0] == "ASC" || $_POST["sort"][0] == "DESC") {
    $query .= " ORDER BY prs " . $_POST['sort'][0];
}
```

Comment: This is going to result in no sort order if someone happens to send something other than ASC or DESC for the sort parameter.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Parameter validation should be done separately and it should just reject that.

Comment: it works, After triggering `ORDER BY prs` how do i trigger `ORDER BY pdt DESC`, Lie three option `order by` date, price low, price high.

Comment: I thought you only wanted `ORDER BY prs` when price is triggered.

Comment: Are you asking how to uncheck the radio buttons after you've selected one of the sort orders? You can't. You could add a third option "Sort by date".

Comment: **NO** i want `ORDER BY pdt DESC` also, how do i trigger

Comment: Yes @Barmar how do i add `Sort by date`